# CSS animation for my website not working in any browser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add animation to create something like a carousel, but the animation part in my CSS is not working.

```css
div#trustw {
  padding: 20px;
}

div#trustc {
  height: 38px;
  background-image: url(https://siasky.net/CAC--w_DduTHuvdgazKKQ87iMMSysgeoGje9_xsadF_qLw);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: animatedBackgroud;
}
```

```html
    <div id="trustw" class="container-fluid">
      <div id="trustc" class="container"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is the keyframes?

Comment: You are doubling up the animation settings as well. You don't need `animation-duration`, `animation-name`, `animation-timing-function` or `animation-iteration-count` since you are already setting those in the `animation` property short-hand.

Comment: it seems that problem is with my keyframes. I'm adding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define the animation:

```css
    @keyframes animatedBackgroud {
      from {background-position: 0%;}
      to {background-position: 100%;}
    }
```

```css
div#trustw {
  padding: 20px;
}

div#trustc {
  height: 38px;
  background-image: url(https://siasky.net/CAC--w_DduTHuvdgazKKQ87iMMSysgeoGje9_xsadF_qLw);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: animatedBackgroud;
}

@keyframes animatedBackgroud {
  from {background-position: 0%;}
  to {background-position: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="trustw" class="container-fluid">
      <div id="trustc" class="container"></div>
    </div>
```